# Updating Fields In an Array of Structure

Tags: c, arrays, windows, data-structures

Within this program I am tasked to create a leaderboard program. Sadly, only 4/6 of the main functions work as intended, that being the fillplayer,addplayer and displaystats functions. I don't seem to grasp the logic in updating the scores within a structure as well as sorting them in descending order.

With the updatescore function, it only identifies the ID of the first user and updates their score, this function would treat the other IDs like they never existed.

With the playerranking function, it only sorts the scores but not the respective holders of said score.

What am i doing wrong? I'm pretty close to finishing the program...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int number,i,key,newscore,a;
struct playerdata
{
  char init[3];
  int id,score;
}playerstats[6];


void welcome ();

void fillplayer()                                    //read player info//
{

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter your Initials (3 Letters).");
        scanf("%s", &playerstats[i].init);
        printf("\n Please enter your score");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i].score);
        playerstats[i].id = ( rand()%2000 ) + 1;
    }
    welcome();
}


void displaystats()                              //Output player info//
{
    printf("\nInitials\tID\t\tScore\t");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s\t\t%d\t\t%d",playerstats[i].init,playerstats[i].id,playerstats[i].score);

    }   
    printf("\n\n");
    welcome();
}

void addplayer()                                    //read one player's info//
{
        printf("\n(This may overwrite the player who is at the bottom of the Leaderboard.)" );
        printf("\n\nPlease enter your Initials (3 Letters).");
        scanf("%s", &playerstats[i+4].init);
        printf("\n Please enter your score");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i+4].score);
        playerstats[i+4].id = ( rand()%2000 ) + 1;
        welcome();


}

int searchplayer(void)
{
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter your player ID");
         scanf("%d", &key);

              if (playerstats[i].id==key)
              {
                  return a;
              }
              else
              {
                return  -1;
              }
    }
}   

void updatescore() 
{
   for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   {

         a=searchplayer();
        if (playerstats[i].id==key)
        {
           printf ("\nYour ID is%d", playerstats[i].id);
           printf("\nEnter your new high score");
           scanf("%d",&newscore);
           if (newscore>playerstats[i].score)
           {
               playerstats[i].score=newscore;
               printf("Score successfully changed to %d", newscore);
           }
               else 
               {
                    printf("\nThis score is less than your current highscore, the high score shall not be changed");
               }
        }       

                else
                {
                printf("\nInvalid ID");
                }
                printf("\n\n");



    }   
    welcome(); 
}








void playerranking()
{
    int temp, swapped;
    while(1)
    {
        swapped=0;
        for (i=0; i<5-1; i++)
        {
             if(playerstats[i].score<playerstats[i+1].score)
             {
                 temp = playerstats[i].score;
                 playerstats[i].score = playerstats[i+1].score;
                 playerstats[i+1].score= temp;
                 swapped = 1;
             }
        }
        if(swapped==0)
        {
            break;
        }


    }
    printf("\n\n");
    displaystats();
    welcome();
}


void exitfunct()
{
    while(1)
    {
        break;
    }
}

void filltest()
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("\n Please enter your Initials");
        scanf("%s",&playerstats[i].init);
        printf("\n Please enter your score");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i].score);
        playerstats[i].id = ( rand()%2000 ) + 1;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    welcome();
}





void welcome()
{    
    printf("\nWelcome to the leaderboard, challenger!");
    printf("\nPlease select an option:");
    printf("\n1-Add 5 players at a time\n2-Display all stats\n3-Update score\n4-Show player ranking\n5-Add 1 player\n6-Exit Program");
    printf("\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
        fillplayer();
        break;

        case 2:
        displaystats();
        break;

        case 3:
        updatescore();
        break;

        case 4:
        playerranking();
        break;

        case 5:
        addplayer();
        break;

        case 6:
        exitfunct();
        break;

        case 7:
        filltest();
        break;

        default:
        printf("\nThis option is invalid");

    }


}





int main()
{
    welcome();    
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using global vars like `key`. Pass it as a parameter: `void updatescore(int key) {...}`. After fixing `searchplayer()`, use it to get the parameter to pass.

```
const int NUM_PLAYERS = 5;

int searchplayer(void)
{
    int key;
    printf("\nEnter your player ID");
    if (1 == scanf("%d", &key)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++) {
            if (playerstats[i].id == key) {
                return i;
            }
         }
         printf("Player ID not found: %d\n", key);
     }
     else {
         puts("Invalid entry.")
     }
     return -1;
}

void updatescore(int key) 
{
    if (key < 0 || key >= NUM_PLAYERS) return;

    int newscore;
    printf ("\nYour ID is %d", playerstats[key].id);
    printf("\nEnter your new high score");
    if (1 == scanf("%d",&newscore) {
        if (newscore > playerstats[key].score) {
            playerstats[key].score = newscore;
            printf("Score successfully changed to %d", newscore);
        }
        else  {
            printf("\nThis score is less than your current highscore, the high score shall not be changed");
        }
    }
    else {
        puts("Invalid entry.")
    }
}

void welcome()
{    
    // Code removed for brevity
        case 3:
        updatescore(searchplayer());
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

as for `updatescore function` problem comes form your `searchplayer function` also when you searched ,you shouldn't use `key` in `updatescore function` again. After search you need this `if-else` in `updatescore function`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        int num = searchplayer();
        if (num == 1)
        {
         statement;
        }
        else
       {
        statement;
        }
}
```

look:

```
int searchplayer(void)
{

printf("\nEnter your player ID");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (playerstats[i].id == key)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

        return  -1;
}
```

in your code if the first player id is entered you will enter `if statement` and return `1` ,but for example if you enter second player id ,since for `i=0` this `if (playerstats[i].id == key)` is wrong function will always return `-1` and so in your `updatescore function` you will always end with `invalid id`.

also you should put your `scanf("%d", &key);` out of loop because with one key you should check `if (playerstats[i].id == key)` not 5 keys.

for your `playerranking function`

to sort struct you should do it manually like this:

```
void playerranking()
{
    char inittmp[3];
    int  idtmp;
    int temp, swapped;
    while (1)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5 - 1; i++)
        {
            if (playerstats[i].score < playerstats[i + 1].score)
            {
                temp = playerstats[i].score;
                playerstats[i].score = playerstats[i + 1].score;
                playerstats[i + 1].score = temp;

                idtmp = playerstats[i].id;
                playerstats[i].id = playerstats[i + 1].id;
                playerstats[i + 1].id = idtmp;

                strcpy(inittmp , playerstats[i].init);
                strcpy(playerstats[i].init , playerstats[i + 1].init);
                strcpy(playerstats[i + 1].init , inittmp);
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == 0)
        {
            break;
        }


    }
    printf("\n\n");
    displaystats();
    welcome();
}
```

with sorting one member of `struct` ,it won't automatically sort other members you should do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can't believe i messed up so bad in the code, it works just as intended!! <3

Comment: @Rekader Feel free .there is no need for thanks. if it really helped you accept the answer.